# What are "BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks"?

Tags: android

Android Lint complain about `assert()` being used, and recommend using *BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks* instead.

I understood perfectly why assert are not safe to use on android, but what *exactly* are "BuildConfig.DEBUG conditional checks" ?

How would the following example code be amended ?

```
Context ctx = getContext();
assert (ctx instanceof FragmentActivity);
fragment_manager = ((FragmentActivity) ctx).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think what lint is trying to say is that add a check of BuildConfig.DEBUG for assert statement

<strike>if(BuildConfig.DEBUG)</strike>

<strike>assert (ctx instanceof FragmentActivity);</strike>

so that assert works only when you are testing the app, but on release versions assert will not be called

BuildConfig.DEBUG will be false when you export a release build.

Edit:
 Looks like you should do something like below rather than using assert

```
 if(BuildConfig.DEBUG && !(ctx instanceof FragmentActivity))
      throw new RuntimeException();
```

instead of assert.

source: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio045released

Some new lint checks, and in particular one which flags uses of the assertion keyword. This does not work reliably on devices and you should use BuildConfig.DEBUG to do conditional checks instead.

Comment: But assert() code is not called/not completely implemented on dalvik, so even when running a test (on an emulator), assert() should not be used.

Comment: AFAIK, assert can be enabled using debug.assert =1 system prop

Comment: According to this post http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65183 "[assert()] was never supported in Dalvik. The system property exists, but is pretty much ignored in various places. There is a reason that this isn't documented or made easy to use."

Comment: I'm finding that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is true when pressing the "bug" play button in Android Studio, or the regular play button. So I'm seeing asserts triggered when I'm actually not "debugging".

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere - BuildConfig.DEBUG is true when you built your APK with a debug configuration. If you're install from ADB or Android Studio (as opposed to the Play Store), you're probably working with a debug build.

Comment: maybe instead of `RuntimeException`, you want to use `AssertionError`